# Mount two same usb device Always in the same port UBUNTU

Tags: shell, usb, devices, kubuntu, usb-device

need to mount two device (identical/equal) at the same port...not difficult but look this:

```
/dev/input/event6 - Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315
/dev/input/event2 - Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315
/dev/input/event3 - 413c_3010
/dev/input/mouse0 - 413c_3010
/dev/input/event4 - Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard
/dev/input/event6 and /dev/input/event2 is my device...
```

sometimes when a reboot my server its mistake confuse the two device and mount the device in event2 -> in event6 and the device in event6 -> in event2

i need that Device A is mount always in event6 Device B is mount always in event2

but this device as the same name and the same parameters

Comment: If you have `udev` on your system, you can use your devices by their identifiers located in `/dev/input/by-id/` instead of their direct mount point

Comment: @oliv Yes but when server turning off ?

Comment: If your server is off, i don't think it's going to handle any input, isn't it?

Comment: @oliv I mean... the devices is the same ... sometimes when a reboot my server its mount the devices in other location or mix it